# DOMDocument::replaceChild() responds results in 500 (Internal Server error)

Tags: domdocument, php

I have a problem. PHP file responds 500 Error. Can't understand what is the problem. The PHP error message is:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'DOMException' with message 'Not Found Error'

Code is below:

```
$dom = new domDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->loadHTML($cont);

$links  = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
$divs   = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');

foreach ($links as $link)
{
    $link->setAttribute('target','_blank');
}

foreach ($images as $image)
{
    $image->setAttribute('style','max-width:405px');
}

foreach ($divs as $div)
{
    $pnode = $dom->createElement('p', $div->nodeValue);
    $dom->replaceChild($pnode, $div); //the problem string
}
```

Update: If the problem string is commented there are no errors.

Comment: Always develop with `display_errors` turned on. 500 is a fatal error in PHP, and the message will be clear.  `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: possible problems: 1) wrong htaccess file, 2)trying to access non-existed method in code 3)error might be not related to the code you listed. Post full example pls so people can test it

Comment: Ok, now it writes: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'DOMException' with message 'Not Found Error'

Comment: Try `$div->parentNode->replaceChild`.

Comment: You are still getting the same error after using `$div->parentNode->replaceChild($pnode, $div);` ?

Comment: Thank you very much! It works! I have no idea how, but it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [air4x](https://stackoverflow.com/users/651354/air4x).

replaceChildren looks up through only one level. In my sutuation it was looking for  element in the  and root.

Solution is below:

```
 $div->parentNode->replaceChild($pnode, $div);
```

Answer (score 1):

The code seems to be OK. Check if you have a DOM/XML php extension enabled in `phpinfo();`. Add

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

to your code or [enable php error showing in .htaccess](https://www.google.cz/search?&q=enable%20php%20error%20showing%20htaccess&oq=enable%20php%20error%20showing%20htaccess).